# Unable to display data from model in template

Tags: python, django

I am trying to display data from a model inside my `post.html` which worked before but now dosen't for some reason I can't figure out.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', ListView.as_view(
        queryset=Tutorials.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:25],
        template_name="tutorials/blog.html"
    )),

    path('<int:pk>', DetailView.as_view(
            model=Tutorials,
            template_name="tutorials/post.html")),
]
```

blog.html

```
{% block  python %}
    {% for Tutorials in object_list %}
        {% if Tutorials.categories == "pythonbasics" %}
            <a href="/tutorials/{{ Tutorials.id }}"><h1>{{ Tutorials.title }}</h1></a>
            <br>
            Created On : {{ Tutorials.date|date:"Y-m-d" }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

post.html

```
{% block content %}
    <h3>{{ Tutorials.title }}</h3>

    <h6> on {{ Tutorials.datetime }}</h6>

    <div class = "code">
        {{ Tutorials.content|linebreaks }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Any errors that you can share?

Comment: there's nothing in the logs it just won't display anything. No errors @mehrdad-pedramfar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `object` name in template:

```
{% block content %}
    <h3>{{ object.title }}</h3>

    <h6> on {{ object.datetime }}</h6>

    <div class = "code">
        {{ object.content|linebreaks }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Or if you want to use `Tutorial` variable, you need to pass `context_object_name=Tutorials` to the view:

```
path('<int:pk>', DetailView.as_view(
            model=Tutorials,
            template_name="tutorials/post.html",
            context_object_name='Tutorials')),
```

Comment: It worked but why? I swear I was running the same code by writing the model name not object. Thank you btw. @neverwalkaloner

Comment: @Sahil probably you used `context_object_name='Tutorials'` argument. If this argument passed to DetailView `Tutorials` variable will be assisiated with object also.

Answer (score 1):

plus for @neverwalkaloner's answer.

The reason why you can use `object` or `context_object_name` is cause you inherit `DetailView`.

In `DetailView`, it has `get_object()` method.

```
def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    """
    Return the object the view is displaying.
    Require `self.queryset` and a `pk` or `slug` argument in the URLconf.
    Subclasses can override this to return any object.
    """
    # Use a custom queryset if provided; this is required for subclasses
    # like DateDetailView
    if queryset is None:
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
    # Next, try looking up by primary key.
    pk = self.kwargs.get(self.pk_url_kwarg)
    slug = self.kwargs.get(self.slug_url_kwarg)
    if pk is not None:
        queryset = queryset.filter(pk=pk)
    # Next, try looking up by slug.
    if slug is not None and (pk is None or self.query_pk_and_slug):
        slug_field = self.get_slug_field()
        queryset = queryset.filter(**{slug_field: slug})
    # If none of those are defined, it's an error.
    if pk is None and slug is None:
        raise AttributeError("Generic detail view %s must be called with "
                             "either an object pk or a slug."
                             % self.__class__.__name__)
    try:
        # Get the single item from the filtered queryset
        obj = queryset.get()
    except queryset.model.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404(_("No %(verbose_name)s found matching the query") %
                      {'verbose_name': queryset.model._meta.verbose_name})
    return obj
```

It will return model object, and also you can override this method.

And in `get()` method in `DetailView`,

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
    return self.render_to_response(context)
```

As you see, it define `self.object` to `self.get_object()` so you can use `self.object` inside `DetailView`.

Finally, you can use `object` in your template because of `get_context_data()`.

`DetailView` basically add 'object' to context, so you can use it.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    """Insert the single object into the context dict."""
    context = {}
    if self.object:
        context['object'] = self.object
        context_object_name = self.get_context_object_name(self.object)
        if context_object_name:
            context[context_object_name] = self.object
    context.update(kwargs)
    return super().get_context_data(**context)
```

It's true that CBV has little bit learning curve, but when you see django source code and read about docs, it's easy to follow.

+I highly recommend [ccbv.co.kr](https://ccbv.co.uk/) - you can see which view and mixin that CBV inherit, and it's methods too.

Answer (score 0):

{% block content %}

#### {{ object.title }}

```
<h6> on {{ object.datetime }}</h6>

<div class = "code">
    {{ object.content|linebreak }}
</div>
```

{% endblock %}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This code is already provided in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50247613/17175441